# Fingerprint to unlock laptop Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Tags: windows-8.1

I was recently upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 7 at work on a Lenovo T440. I have set up fingerprint login. When I boot Windows, I can swipe my finger and I'm logged in - no typing in my user, password. Once I'm logged in and lock the screen, I can no longer use the fingerprint sensor to unlock; instead, I have to type in my user AND password. How do I set it up so I can always use the fingerprint sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. "Display user information when the session is locked" needs to be set to at least "User display" for it to work. Start -> Local Security Policy. Then Local Policies -> Security Options.

Comment: It worked for me only setting it to "User display name, domain and user names". Thanks a million.